# CSS file is being cached even after clearing cache and changing the CSS version

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, browser-cache

I have a css file and to test it, I added some code to the bottom that just changed the color of a small section on the site. It took about 15 minutes but eventually it loaded and updated the CSS. Then when I removed it to see how long it will take to come off again, the code still loads and it has been about 30 minutes. I tried clearing my browser cache as well as changing the version of the CSS file. The version (when I inspect the source code on the browser) is updated to v2 like it should be but the file still contains the code from v1. Would it be because of the host caching the file or something? When I ran into this problem before, changing the version of the css file worked but it is not this time. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Oh as another note I am using the below code to enque the css file and it is in WordPress:

```
function my_theme_styles() {
// Enqueue our style.css with our own version

wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array(), '202107v1'); 
}
```

I also know there are other things on stackoverflow but they all just say to either clear the browser cache or to change the version at the end of the css file which both options I have already tried with no success.

Comment: this way : `wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css?v=202107v1', ..`

Comment: That still has me end up with the same thing though. I still would get /style.css?ver=202107v1' in the source code and it still doesn't load the new CSS content, just the version is changed but I still have the same issue

Comment: how is the generated source code on the browser for this part ?

Comment: Is this local or on a hosted server? If it's hosted, does your host use Cloudflare or another caching layer?

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin like W3 Total Cache or LS Cache on WordPress? Are you using CDN services like Cloudflare? Are you using shared hosting? A lot of shared hosting is also using some form of cache system like Cloudflare. If everything is okay, Ctrl+Shift+R should work.

Comment: Yes I believe we are using Cloudflare. Is there a problem with cloudflare hosting that it caches files or something? That would be the only difference from the other websites I have built so I would assume it would have to be something with cloudflare right? is there anything I can do to fix that so it does not do that?

Comment: @SahriarSaikat thank you for pointing out that it could be cloudflare, I checked the settings in cloudflare (which I didn't have access to until today) and found that they were using the query level "ignore query string" which was making it not update. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Sahriar Saikat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4240853/sahriar-saikat) mentioned in the comments that it could be cloudflare caching the file and he was right. I checked the settings in cloudflare (which I didn't have access to until today) and found that they were using the query level "ignore query string" which was making it not update. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is also a Cloudflare plugin for WordPress which you can use to clear Cloudflare cache and other stuff from your site if you are changing your site a lot for development. I simply disable the CDN/reverse proxy of Cloudflare and use it for "DNS only" when I am developing my site. Be careful though, your server ip might be exposed if you do it or enable Developer mode. I mostly use seperate disposible server for developing.